# How do you reference one XAML object value from another?

Tags: c#, xaml

XAML is a capable of building trees of C# objects, just as you would in code; however, although I can instantiate objects no problem, I am stuck with the syntax for initialising one to the value of another (if this is even possible).

To illustrate, consider the following pointless example:

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyClass">

    <x:String x:Name="MyString">Hello</x:String>

    <x:String x:Name="MyString2">STUCK FOR SYNTAX HERE</x:String>
```

The strings are instantiated.  I can see them in the debugger and I can write code to manipulate them just as if they were normal pieces of C# code.  My question is: can I use the value of the first string 'Hello' to initialise the second string?  Or, put more generally, can I access the value of one XAML object from another XAML object?

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Well, this is what data binding is used for. But binding is a markup extension, hence, can't be treated as "pure" XAML.

Comment: Thank you for that comment.  It has caused me to realise that I am hazy on the difference between pure XAML and a markup extension.  Time for more reading...

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippet does not compile.  The answer to your question is no, and going out on a limb here, but you're likely misusing XAML.  As Dennis said in the comment, you should be using data-binding.  The closest thing that matches what you're trying to do is this:

```
<Window ....
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" >
    <Window.Resources>
        <system:String x:Key="MyString">Hello</system:String>
        <system:String x:Key="MyString2">STUCK FOR SYNTAX HERE</system:String>
    </Window.Resources>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                <Binding Source="{StaticResource MyString}" />
                <Binding Source="{StaticResource MyString2}" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</Window>
```

The following code would show "Hello - STUCK FOR SYNTAX HERE" in a text block.

The reason you can't concat strings in XAML is because you're literally initializing a `System.String` which does not support any kind of other type markup.

Comment: Sorry the code didn't compile.  It did on my machine, but I managed to chop some off when copying it.  Doh!  I think I need to try to come up with a better code example.  I'm not trying to concatenate strings.  I just thought strings would make the simplest and shortest example of what I am trying to get at.  But, as you say, the problem with strings is that they don't support the type of initialisation I am trying to do.  I will try to come up with a better example.